# How to create a scene for rendering?

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, rigid-body-simulation

I modeled some earrings and want to render them now. Any tips on how to achieve this type of scene (earrings laying on a fabric/cloth)? I've tried adding a cloth made in Marvelous Designer and made the earrings fall down onto it, which didn't really work as they either fell through or floated above. I'm new to physics and stuff in blender, thank you.[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest not relying on the physics engine at all and instead place them manually.  Just like an actual jewler, they wouldn't repeatedly throw jewlery down until it looked just right, they would place them exactly where they want them.  It sounds like a good exercise in using the rotation axis shortcuts!

<kbd>x</kbd>
<kbd>y</kbd>
<kbd>z</kbd>